# Working with iBeacon?

Tags: ibeacon

I want to create an app to use with iBeacon. I found some examples but I can't understand how to use iBeacon to collect informations of an webservice.

For example, I want to create an promotion to one store on my panel(webservice) and when the custommers are aproximate of this store with iBeacon the app goes display the promotion.

To do this example I need a webservice to communicate with iBeacon ? And if I need, how could iBeacon communicate with webservice to get the promotions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task has these stages in implementation:

1. Detect event with iBeacon: enter the region, leave the region
2. Send request to webservice to get data for detected event for particular iBeacon (UUID, major value, minor value, name of device)
3. Show data from webservice to user of your application
4. Store user action if it is needed.

Comment: but, If I follow your example the devices(android or ios) need has internet ? I'm question this because I saw an app that uses iBeacon and device not need internet. The device only communicate with iBeacon and after communicate display the promotions, note that devices no has internet access. The app's name is Tagpoint and this app has their own beacons.

Comment: Promotion can be stored localy in app's database or hardcoded. You have mentioned webservice so I decided that interaction is...

Comment: thanks for your help. You said promotions can be stored locally or hardcoded, so, when I add any promotion on my webservice the app need to syncronize and add these promotions on database of device and when device locate iBeacon does make search locally database and get promotions of store ? That's it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BONI](http://boni.io) platform. BONI allows you to register iBeacons and then map content items to each iBeacon. Then using BONI Cordova SDK you can easily develop a hybrid mobile app that will detect iBeacons and exchange the signal that receive from them for the already defined content items. You can read more on the [BONI Documentation Page](http://boni.io/docs/).